# java JNA interface auto generator

Tags: java, dll, interface, generator, jna

I have a third-party DLL, which consists of fairly a big number of interrelated classes (maybe written in C++) , the Java Native Access package wants the programmer to write an interface for each and every class within the DLL, In VB.net the Object Explorer makes life a piece of cake; however, in java i couldn't find such a tool.

Are there any tools that takes the DLL file and generate all needed JNA interfaces ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

[JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) can "compile" native headers in order to generate JNA mappings, with some limited C++ support.

Comment: JNAerator had been migrated to [GitHub: https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator). However it hasn't been updated in more than 6 years. Any alternatives?